# Codeigniter 3 failed to write cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-3

I tried to write caches using codeigniter 3 helper in my application :

```
$this->cache->save($cacheKey, $data, 150);
```

I already made sure the $data is not empty,
But when i open the cache folder, there is no result there.
I put my application inside windows server, so my first thought was the windows permissions, however the permission is already in full control like so :

[image: permission]

How to fix this ?

**Update 1**

As suggested by Olivier , i tried to create txt file using php in that folder, and the txt file was sucessfully created

```
$myfile = fopen(APPPATH."cache/testfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, "John Doe\n");
fclose($myfile);
```

[image: created .txt file]

**Update 2**

This is how i load the cache driver,

```
//cache driver load
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file'));

// cache path
$config['cache_path'] = '';
```

The cache value ($data) was actually a spreadsheet file which was produced by the phpspreadsheet library.

Comment: Try explicitly creating a file in that directory through PHP and you'll see if it is a permission issue or not.

Comment: @Olivier , i tried it and sucesfully created, please see my updated question

Comment: Did you check the value of `$cacheKey`? Do you have PHP errors enabled (or did you check the PHP error log)?

Comment: I did enabled the log error and nothing happened there, also i tried to dump the $cahceKy and the result was there cached-6534eec863ced3.48034648

Comment: Can you show the line that loads the cache driver?

Comment: There is some pretty key info missing here.  1) What is your configured `cache_path`? 2) How are you loading the cache driver, and which one? 3) "*when i open the cache folder*" - what folder, exactly, are you looking in?  4) Are you able to retrieve your cached value?  What does `$this->cache->get($cacheKey);` show?

Comment: "*i tried to dump the $cahceKy and the result was there cached-6534eec863ced3.48034648*" - it is not clear from your wording if you mean that is the cached value, or that is $cacheKey?

Comment: @Olivier please see my updated question on how i load the driver

Comment: @Don'tPanic 1. I use the defauld application/cache path folder, 2. Please see my updated question, 3. application/cache folder, 4. The cache value was a spreadsheet from phpspreadsheet

Comment: OK ... your code specifies to use the APC cache driver.  APC caches to memory, not files on disk.

Comment: "*The cache value was a spreadsheet from phpspreadsheet*" - I did not ask what the cached value is.  I am asking if you were able to retrieve your cached value.  In other words, does your cache seem to be working? You are asking about cache files on disk, but you did not mention if you are asking because the cache is not working?  Or it is working, and you are just curious?

Comment: @Don'tPanic already tried using the file based caching driver according to this docs https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/caching.html#toc-entry-5 the and got the same result
And i wasn't able to get the cache value either as no cache file created on the cache folder

Comment: Still seems like some potential confusion here.  Try the most basic example to verify the problem. First check and remove any cache driver being autoloaded in `config/autoload.php`, or anywhere else.  Then in a controller, say your home page, add this code: `$this->load->driver('cache', ['adapter' => 'file']);
$this->cache->save('foo', 'bar', 10);
var_dump($this->cache->get('foo'));
die();`.  Visit the home page and see what is displayed.  If nothing, check your CI, PHP, and web server logs.

Comment: did you check if driver is supported by your hosting environment? `if ($this->cache->apc->is_supported())...`

Comment: @Vickel yes its supported i tested it with simple foo bar content like Don't Panic have mentioned, but when the contents is from phpspreadsheet its failed to write that cache